# Perl how to extract all words matching a pattern and build processed lists

Tags: regex, perl, loops, pattern-matching

So I have a file "Myoutput test.txt" of the form

```
#Some comments
#some more comments
A X word123_0988b 0.00132 -123.4 567
T E word123_0988b 0.00456 -231.4 897
H D word123_0988b 1.3132 -120.2 757
F Y word234_09876b 0.1231 -12344 789
A T word234_09876b 0.34531 -144 789
F Y word234_09876b 0.1231 -12344 789
G L word890_0987a 0.00012 -12312 654
```

And I want to build a list of the form

```
{{word123_0988b,A,T,H},{word234_09876b,F,A,F},{word890_0987a,G}}
```

where the first position of each sublist is the identifier in the 3rd column, and the other letters are all of the letters in the first column which this identifier is associated with.

To do this I was thinking about doing this:

1. Extract all identifiers in the 3rd column, delete duplicates;
2. For each identifier, select all lines with this identifier, extract the elements in column 1, push these into an array of the form {identified,1stcol1,2ndcol1,3rdcol1}.

However, I can't even do the 1st point. Here's where I got until now:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir='D:\test';
my ($out,$file);

open $out,"<", "$dir\\Myoutput test.txt" or die "problem opening out $!";

my @file = grep (!/^#/,<$out>); #ignores commented lines

while ($file =~ /(\w*word\w*)/g){
    print "$1\n"; #would print all words matching "word"
}

close $out;
```

Could someone give me some tips or any guidance on how to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you:

```
my @file = grep (!/^#/,<$out>);
```

you're forcing the creation of a complete list of the file's lines, just to skip those which begin with `#`.  Typically, this is handled in a `while` loop, so only one line at a time is read from the file, and skipped if not wanted.

The data structure that would help here is a hash of arrays (HoA), where the keys are the identifiers and the values are references to lists of column 1 letters.  Here's how this can be done:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
local $" = ',';

while (<DATA>) {
    next if /^#/;
    my @cols = split ' ', $_, 4;
    push @{ $hash{ $cols[2] } }, $cols[0];
}

print '{';
print "{$_,@{ $hash{$_} }}" for sort keys %hash;
print '}';

__END__
#Some comments
#some more comments
A X word123_0988b 0.00132 -123.4 567
T E word123_0988b 0.00456 -231.4 897
H D word123_0988b 1.3132 -120.2 757
F Y word234_09876b 0.1231 -12344 789
A T word234_09876b 0.34531 -144 789
F Y word234_09876b 0.1231 -12344 789
G L word890_0987a 0.00012 -12312 654
```

Output:

```
{{word123_0988b,A,T,H}{word234_09876b,F,A,F}{word890_0987a,G}}
```

The `local $" = ',';` notation makes `,` `print` between array elements when the array is interpolated (`print`ed within a string).  Each line is `split` setting `split`'s LIMIT to 4, since only the first three columns are significant (`split`ting terminates after the third column).  The `push` line creates the HoA.  Finally, the HoA is `print`ed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: two questions: first, what does the `@` in `@{ $hash{$_}}` do? second, from your answer I can see that the elements of col1 is ordered, but can I be sure this is the case? Are they ordered as they appear?

Comment: @Sosi - `$hash{$_}` denotes a hash element and `@{ $hash{$_} }` uses it as an array, the sigil `@` meaning "array."  So we're actually `push`ing the first column's values onto an array.  The elements are ordered as they appear, as the hash keys (column three values) are sorted in the `print`ing routine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you aren't iterating through your array `@file`. You declared `$file` when you declared `$out`, so that's why you don't get any errors. You'll want to cycle through the array using a `for` loop instead. Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $out;

open $out,"<", "test.txt" or die "problem opening out $!";

my @file = grep (!/^#/,<$out>); #ignores commented lines

for my $file (@file) {
        if ( $file =~ /(\w*word\w*)/g) {
                print "$1\n"; #would print all words matching "word"
        }
}
close $out;
```

I changed the open statement so you'll have to change it back to your input file. Hopefully this gets you past being stuck on the first point. The output looks like:

```
matt@mattpc:~/Documents/test/4$ perl test.pl 
word123_0988b
word123_0988b
word123_0988b
word234_09876b
word234_09876b
word234_09876b
word890_0987a
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, at most I was getting some errors of undeclared vars in the statement `while ($file =~ /(\w*word\w*)/g){`, which was confusing me since I had declared it in the beginning! I get a similar ouput in my real file, thanks!